# Why does ping to the same interface fail when loop-back is down?

Tags: networking, drivers, ping

When I down the loopback interface and try to ping my own IP, it's showing 100% packet loss, even when my `eth0` is up. Why is this?

Here's what I did:

```
root@faisal-desktop# ifconfig lo down
root@faisal-desktop# ping -I eth0 172.16.10.112 -c 2
PING 172.16.10.112 (172.16.10.112) from 172.16.10.112 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 172.16.10.112 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1007ms

root@faisal-desktop# ifconfig
eth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:f6:82:03  
         inet addr:172.16.10.112  Bcast:172.16.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
         inet6 addr: fe80::6ef0:49ff:fef6:8203/64 Scope:Link
                          .
                          .
```

Check the ifconfig **TX packets count**

```
root@faisal-desktop# ifconfig 
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:f6:82:03  
      inet addr:172.16.10.112  Bcast:172.16.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6ef0:49ff:fef6:8203/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:25822 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24825 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:19581301 (19.5 MB)  TX bytes:4013322 (4.0 MB)
      Interrupt:26 Base address:0x6000 

root@faisal-desktop# ping -c 1 -I eth0 172.16.10.112
PING 172.16.10.112 (172.16.10.112) from 172.16.10.112 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 172.16.10.112 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

root@faisal-desktop# ifconfig 
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:f6:82:03  
      inet addr:172.16.10.112  Bcast:172.16.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6ef0:49ff:fef6:8203/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:25840 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24845 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:19588641 (19.5 MB)  TX bytes:4017338 (4.0 MB)
      Interrupt:26 Base address:0x6000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer 
Pinging to same interface uses loopback interface only. [Check here](http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/link_lay.htm)
And one doubt, in which function/module does the ip checking and replacing with loopback?


[image: Loopback]

Comment: It doesn't say "*pinging to the same **interface**.*" it says "*Anything sent to one of the host's own **IP addresses** is sent to the loopback interface.*" It also says "*a loopback interface [...] allows a client and server on the same host to communicate with each other using TCP/IP.*" The implication is that without a loopback interface this is not possible.

Comment: Yea thats it. I have a doubt, do you know in which module / function that comparison happens?

Comment: Alright, but i couldn't find it. Can anyone point out the file/function which is responsible for comparing packets(sending out) destination ip with interfaces ip, and changing to loopback !!.

Comment: I doubt its in _$(KERNEL_SOURCE)/net/ipv4/route.c_

Answer (score 2):

> Why does ping to the same interface fail when loop-back is down?

Because you don't ping an interface you ping an IP-address.

Your operating system works out which interface is the most appropriate one to use based on the target IP-address. If the target IP-address is your own, the most appropriate interface to use is the loopback interface as it has the lowest overheads.

Comment: Agreed but now there is no loopback interface, so it should use other appropriate one. But it is not even calling the driver **start_xmit** function.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's simply verify ("**via dev lo**"):

```
# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8b:38:0c
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe8b:380c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:550 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:60478 (59.0 KiB)  TX bytes:38274 (37.3 KiB)

# ip ro get 10.0.2.15
local 10.0.2.15 dev lo src 10.0.2.15
    cache
```